# WordPress Advance custom fields trying to get image url to insert in a src or href property

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have ACF repeater for an image. And I am passing the image url as a return value using a repeater. everything seems to work fine. But now I have a custom js slider in which I need to pass those images url. but I am unable to get it to work.

My **Repeater name** is : **boat_product_slider** and the **image field name** is : **slider_image**
Please have a look at the screenshot for better understanding.

Screenshot :

[image: images url are placed somewhere else instead of getting placed at src or href property]

My Code :

```
<div class="slider-inner">
      <?php 
                      echo '<ul>';
           if( have_rows('boat_product_slider') ): while ( have_rows('boat_product_slider') ) : the_row(); 
     echo '<li><a class="ns-img" href='.the_sub_field('slider_image').'></a></li>';
          endwhile; endif;
         echo '</ul>';

         ?>        
      <div id="thumbnail-slider">
         <div class="inner">
            <ul>
               <?php 
               if( have_rows('boat_product_slider') ): while ( have_rows('boat_product_slider') ) : the_row(); 
                          echo "<li>";
                                    echo "<img class='thumb' src=".the_sub_field('slider_image')." />";
                                    echo "</li>";
                  endwhile; endif;
                                     ?>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

I guess I am missing out here something really silly.

Comment: You should spend some time reading the ACF documentation. There is a subtle, but very important difference between `the_sub_field()` and `get_sub_field()`. Writing `the_sub_field()` is the *exact* same as writing `echo get_sub_field()`. If you want to concat the values, you need to use something like `echo '<img src=" ' . GET_sub_field('image') . ' ">';` If you use `THE_sub_field('image')`, then the value is displayed immediately, which is what's causing your issue.

Comment: For example, in your answer that you posted, you have `echo the_sub_field('slider_image');` which is the same as writing `echo echo get_sub_field('slider_image');`. The `echo` is not needed when using `the_sub_field()`. This subtle difference in the function names is the same throughout most of WordPress. [`the_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/) Vs [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) is just one example of it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to resolve on my own.

instead of using  in entire block and having to use '.' to add the_sub_field() method/function.

I created a new

for better understanding please look at the code below.

Code after :

```
 <div class="slider-inner">
      <?php 
                      echo '<ul>';
           if( have_rows('boat_product_slider') ): while ( have_rows('boat_product_slider') ) : the_row(); 
     echo '<li><a class="ns-img" 

href=';?><?php echo the_sub_field('slider_image'); // This bit is new

echo '></a></li>';
          endwhile; endif;
         echo '</ul>';

         ?>        
      <div id="thumbnail-slider">
         <div class="inner">
            <ul>
               <?php 
               if( have_rows('boat_product_slider') ): while ( have_rows('boat_product_slider') ) : the_row(); 
                          echo "<li>";
                                    echo "<img class='thumb' 

src=";?><?php echo the_sub_field('slider_image'); echo " />"; // This bit is new

                                    echo "</li>";
                  endwhile; endif;
                                     ?>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```